# Xcode showing "Use of undeclared Identifier" error for C++ inheritance

Tags: c++, xcode, inheritance, identifier

I am getting this error "Use of undeclared Identifier "Main" in Xcode when I try to inherit a class. I am unable to find out why this error is showing up. Please someone help.

My sample code which is failing in Xcode. **foo** is the base class

**foo.h**

```
#ifndef cpp_practice_foo_h
#define cpp_practice_foo_h
class Foo {
public:
    void fooFunc();
};


#endif
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void Foo::fooFunc() {
    cout<< "Hola from Foo!" << endl;
}
```

**main.h**

```
#ifndef cpp_practice_main_h
#define cpp_practice_main_h
#include "foo.h"
class Main :: public Foo
{
public:
    void mainFunc();

};
#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"
using namespace std;

void Main::mainFunc() {
    cout<< "Hola from Boo" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

The line below in main.h is where the error is showing up.

**class Main :: public Foo**

Comment: Replace `::` with `:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove second `:` - change

```
class Main :: public Foo
```

to

```
class Main : public Foo
```